# What does 一色 mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, usage, nuances

What does 一色 mean in the first part of the first sentence of [this article](https://mainichi.jp/senkyo/articles/20170922/ddm/002/010/102000c) (about Abe's dissolving of the Diet's lower chamber in a snap election)? I don't quite understand what its trying to say?

> 世間は衆院解散一色だが、内閣改造を受けた安倍晋三首相の８月３日の記者会見を思い出してみよう。「結果本位の仕事人内閣」と語り、森友・加計（かけ）学園問題では透明性向上や野党が求める臨時国会への対応を約束した。北朝鮮の脅威も強調した。解散すれば仕事の結果はゼロ、約束はご破算、政治空白も生じる。究極の自己都合か、老練な宰相の勝負手か－－。【岸達也、和田浩幸】
>
> あの日、首相は「原点に立ち返り」「謙虚に丁寧に」「真摯（しんし）に受け止め」と森友・加計疑惑への反…

Now, I THINK what "世間は衆院解散一色だが" means is "Society generally understands the lower chamber's dissolution, but...", but I still don't quite get it, with the 一色 part especially throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goo辞書 says:

> #### [いっ‐しょく【一色】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/13347/meaning/m0u/)
>
> ２ 全体が**同じ一つの傾向**でおおわれること。「町は祭り一色に塗りつぶされた」

jisho.org says:

> #### [一色](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E8%89%B2)
>
> 2. same tendency; everyone being caught up in the same thing​
>      街はクリスマスムード一色…もうじきイブだ。 The streets are in full Christmas mode - it's almost Christmas Eve.

So 世間は～一色だ means "everyone seems to be {welcoming / discussing / interested in} ～" or maybe simply "Japan is now fully in a 解散 mood". I think the safer choice would be "interested in" here, because obviously not everyone welcomes the dissolution.